# Algorithm to solve system of nonlinear equations

Tags: algorithms, nonlinear-equations, iterative-method, newton-method

I would like some tips in figuring out a good algorithm to find the solution of the following system. Let $\theta$ be a constant in $(0,1)$, let $i,l=1,...,N$, let $a_{l}$ and $b_{i,l}$ be some constants with $a_l \in (0,1)$ and $b_{i,l}>0$ for all $i,l$. Consider the following system of equations in unknowns $z_{1},...,z_{N}$ and $p_{1},...,p_{N}$:$$a_{l}=\sum_{i}\left(\frac{b_{i,l}}{\sum_{i}b_{i,l}}\right)\frac{1}{1+p_{l}z_{i}},l=1,...,N$$ $$\frac{1}{1+z_{i}^{\theta}}=\sum_{l}\left(\frac{b_{i,l}}{\sum_{l}b_{i,l}}\right)\frac{1}{1+p_{l}z_{i}},i=1,...,N$$

I am focusing on real and positive solutions.

Although I don't understand why, Newton methods don't seem reliable, so I have focused on iteration algorithms. One can construct a mapping $ p \rightarrow p'$  as follows: first take $p$  and solve for $z$  from the second set of equations and then go to the first set of equations with that $z$  and solve for $p'$. If $\theta<0$ then this is a contraction mapping, and it stays in some box, implying that there is a unique solution and one can find it using this iteration. But now I want to focus on $\theta\in(0,1)$.

One idea is to again construct an iteration from $p$ to $p'$ but not reversing the one above: first take $p$  and solve for $z$  from the first set of equations and then go to the second set of equations with that $z$  and solve for $p'$. But here solving each set of equations is more involved as I cannot solve them separately, and so again I am at the mercy of fsolve which doesn't seem to work.

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Good implementations of Newton's method are reliable. Poor implementations of Newton's method are unreliable.

Comment: The problem is that for many initial points Newton (fsolve) sends the algorithm in the wrong direction and it diverges. So the codes needs to spend a lot of time finding appropriate initial points. This is something that one does not encounter with an iteration using a contraction mapping.

Comment: Try sticking it in a global optimization solver, such as BARON,  with equations as constraints, and no (or constant) objective function.

Comment: How is Newton's method failing? IIRC `fsolve` has some relatively robust globalization techniques if you know how to ask for them. Additionally, reparameterizing your positive variables as exponentials might help to make the problem completely unconstrained.